# JSON string not being parsed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to store digital signature in database via rails application.

I am using javascript plugin that will convert signature into JSON string. Next I pluck JSON string  from params and stored in a variable. Now I want to regenerate the signature by giving the plucked JSON string to a reverse javascript function.

The reverse function works fine if I set a variable in javascript directly to the JSON string and pass it to the function. However it does not work when I assign the variable to my rails variable which stores JSON string. The value of JSON string is exactly the same in both cases.

In first case the typeof var shows obj.obj type correctly but in second case it shows as a string. I tired every trick to parse using JSON and Jquery but it does not work.

My rails controller :

```
@recipient_signature = params[:recipient_signature]
```

My view where I want to see generated signature using the JSON string.

```
  var sig = "<%=@recipient_signature%>";
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.sigPad').signaturePad({displayOnly:true}).regenerate(sig);
    });
```

The above case does not work even though the value in @recipient_signature is correctly formed JSON string.

But when I assign the same JSON string to sig like below it works...

```
var sig =  [{"lx":55,"ly":25,"mx":55,"my":24},{"lx":55,"ly":25,"mx":55,"my":25}....'];
```

This JSON string is same as in @recipient_signature and shows up in `<%=@recipient_signature%> correctly.`

Javascript somehow does not recoganize it as an array in first case and does in second case... how to fix it?

Comment: "It works fine if I " what? Your JSON look fine, can you install firebug and copy the error in console log here>?

Comment: *"But when I assign the same JSON string to sig like below it works..."* That's not a JSON string. That's Array and Object literal syntax.

Comment: you just need write 
var sig = '<%= j @recipient_signature %>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping your json in quotes and using the variable in html encoded form:

```
var sig = "<%=@recipient_signature%>";
```

Should be

```
var sig = <%=raw @recipient_signature%>;
```

Or you should parse the json:

```
var sig = JSON.parse('<%=raw @recipient_signature%>');
```

Comment: Need to use single quotes in `JSON.parse('<%...` because the output of that variable contains double quotes. I'm not sure that that last example will help with injection attacks, because the value of the server-side variable is already being injected directly into the page (as compared to being retrieved via Ajax), so the server-side variable could be something like: `abc"); alert("Injected code` which the browser would see as `var sig = JSON.parse("abc"); alert("Injected code");`

Comment: @user1570144 You need to disable html escaping of the variable. I've updated for that.

Comment: Single quotes does not work. I need to search replace &quot with ". How to do that in javascript?

Comment: @nnnnnn Actually I agree. I'll remove the comment about injection for the JSON.parse method, and just assume the server is checking for validity.

Comment: This works:                                                           var sig = JSON.parse('<%=raw @recipient_signature%>');

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes. That is, change:

```
var sig = "<%=@recipient_signature%>";
```

to

```
var sig = <%=@recipient_signature%>;
```

That way when the browser receives it it will look like your second example that works.

Note that that isn't really using JSON, it is simply using your server-side code to output a JS array literal directly into the JS code.

Comment: If you use your browser's "View Page Source" option what does the code look like?

Comment: var sig = "[{&quot;lx&quot;:51,&quot;ly&quot;:41,&quot;mx&quot;:51,&quot;my&quot;:40},{&quot;lx&quot;....

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your assignment to sig with double quotes around it is causing a problem - try single quotes.